# The second floating div in chrome clears down before first div

Tags: css, google-chrome, html, css-float

Two divs are next to eachother, both floating left within a wrapper. In IE and firefox they appear correctly, but in Chrome, the 2nd floating div clears down below Div A. When I remove "float:left" in the css, it goes to the correct position in Chrome, but clears down in IE and firefox (as it should). I dont know why it is appearing this way in Chrome. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The HTML and CSS would be useful to answer this.
2. If you have just two divs and you want them to float next to one another, then set a width on each of them and float one left and float the other right.  Remember to leave some space in between the two.

Comment: this is it. I totally forgot to add a width for div B. Thanks to you and all the other advice

Answer (score 6):

in my case i use `display:inline-table` for the parent element of the floated elements.. Even if it is not a table.

I used the `display:inline-table` in order to fix the bug that google chrome had encountered..

Answer (score 2):

I've same issue in Chrome and I solve it by giving `display:inline-table` to parent div

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple - just add the div which contains all these divs an attribute: `display: table;` - it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had multiple css float left divs with text links inside and the container was over lapping on the right of each. The fix was to remove space in the link display text. eg. `...> TEXT </a>` to `...>TEXT</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You must give 1 div the height

For example

Div 1

```
.oneColFixCtrHdr #mainContent {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: 375px;
    height: 0px; /* deze hoogte op 0 instellen, die bepaal je met de onderstaande div. */
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Div 2

```
.oneColFixCtrHdr #maincontent2 {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: 390px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    border-left-style: groove;
```

Comment: hi @wouter to make css readable on StackOverflow you can use the { } (code) button in the editor. That way you will get nice formatted and coloured code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome - Seems this issue has something to do with *display* attribute of parent element. I had same issue and did lot of search. Finally i got it fixed by removing *display* CSS attribute of parent TD tag. I also obsorved one wiered thing. When i had *display:block;* for parent a TD table element, in Chrome, **colspan** was not working (in IE it was working fine). I scratched my lots of hairs finding this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem with Div and its Children Span both had float right, to solve i just added display inline to the Div parent and now it works fine in Chrome and Safari both.

Answer (score 1):

I wrapped everything in `<div style="display:inline;"> ... code .. </div>` and solved the problem.

Comment: This is what worked for me without having to add silly styles or elements to my markup.

Answer (score 0):

1. Without a code example this really is just guessing
2. I am not sure how Chrome works but I do know IE ads its own styles. Did you use a css reset? most cross browser issues can be fixed by this.
3. Sounds like the combined width of the 2 floating divs exceeds the width of the wrapper. Try setting the wrapper width to 100% or no width... or reducing the width of the two floating divs.
4. do you have any display: inline, block etc style properties set on any of those divs?

Comment: ugh @ "IE ads its own styles"... sure browsers may differ on default styles, except in strict mode, but none of them add their own styles.

Answer (score 0):

What about setting display:inline-block and the width for both divs?

EDIT: Setting a max-width of %50 for each one would work in all browsers except IE6, assuming there's no padding/margin set.

Comment: this could work... is inline-block supported by all browsers though?

Comment: it works for me in IE7/IE8 and I know chrome supports it.  If it doesn't work in IE6, it shouldn't make a difference anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced with the same problem. Chrome incorrectly displays divs with float. The block is displayed under the first. Not aside how I expected.
Solition is simple! **Surround both blocks with *div* that no any other sisterly blocks inside**.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where I had a container div with a bunch of inner divs that had the float:left property set. My last inner div (most right) also wrapped down.
I fixed my problem by making sure that the combined inner divs with margins does not exceed the width of the container div.

Chrome's developer tool similar to firebug was great in helping me fix the problem.
For my container div I did not explicitly set a width but chrome's developer tool could show me the inherited width. I then looked at all the widths of the inner divs combined and then adjusted some of the inner div's width.

Answer (score 0):

also similar issue with floating child div's. In my case .. I was floating a surrounding div to right, that contained h3 element (with text-align property) - followed by 2 child block elements.

**Intent** center h3 text, in relation to child block elements below it.

-

**Problem?** I did not have a set **width** for block child elements.. Why? I wanted the width to hold distinct padding on left / right relative to text amount in that container. eg. **padding:10px 30px;**

**Solution** I resorted to setting a width to surrounding and child divs, also center aligning text  on child divs to give similar results of first case attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. I had two divs with float: left inside a table td -- I had to set the table td style to include style="text-align: left;" for them to correctly align.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no HTML hero so in my case the problem was really silly.

> It was just a **syntax error** so be sure you check all your syntax before you start pulling your hair out like I did.
>
> And SAFARI was completely ignoring it and displaying the divs correctly floated so I got really confused.

BASICALLY it  was an unclosed div tag that was creating the problem :

```
<div class="seperator" </div>    instead of    <div class="seperator"> </div>
```

Comment: hmm, I'm just reading original question and trying to figure out where you found that "broken" DIV??? Basically, it's CSS positioning question and I don't see how your answer helps in solving this specific problem.